# Cheapest way of rectifying 60hz -> 30hz 120V AC to halve speed of PSC induction motor

Tags: rectifier, induction-motor, waveform

I am trying to slow down a PSC motor.  (VFD’s are expensive)

I can cheaply rectify AC into the following waveform.

2 positive peaks then 2 negative peaks repeating. 
It would look like pictured.

If feeding this modified AC waveform into an induction motor, would the resulting synchronous speed become halved?  Or would the motor work like crap/not at all? (Maybe some caps could smooth out the dip between consecutive peaks for better performance)

What’s the cheapest way to halve speed?

I don’t want to operate at high slip with reduced voltage due to potential hum.[image: 60hz -> 30hz rectification]

This motor is running a fan and I want to reduce speed/CFM to quiet the monster down.

Comment: Voltage also has to go down at least proportionally or the motor will burn up. Chinese VFDs are pretty reasonably priced.

Comment: how big is the fan?  small-ish fans just use a series capacitor

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  Luckily the motor I am using is one connected to a furnance fan.  Furnace motors have 3 speed controls.  These speed controls use an autotransformer to step-down line voltage being supplied to the motor.  Using the lowest setting (lower supplied voltage) does not change the synchronous speed of the motor.  It has the motor operate at high slip.  If I step down the input frequency via a cycloconverter , I can use the already present auto transformer (low/med wiring) to prevent heat issues.  -- Thanks for the tip, wasnt aware you had to lower voltage when changing the frequency.

Comment: @Jasen  What would a series capacitor do when wiring in series with the motor?  I am not aware of this trick.

Comment: it will limit the current reducing torque, voltage and speed. this is common on ceiling fans, where using a multi-tapped winding is impractical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system that you are describing is called a cycloconverter. An example is shown below. The example shows the frequency as 1/3 of the input power frequency. I believe that is about as high a frequency has cycloconverters can operate successfully with induction motors.

[image]

Excerpt from F. F. Mazda "Thyristor Control" John Wiley & Sons 1973

Comment: Thanks for the resource and pointing what topic to look into.  I have some more research to do.